# Change the width of JTable column

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I need to change the column width size of my `JTable`. Please look at the following code which will use to display values. But I don't know how to maximize the width of the table column.

please let me know how to configure my code.

```
public void displayTable(JTable table){

    Vector columns = new Vector(getIndividual(0).chromosomeColumnCount()+1);

    columns.add("Staff Names");

        for(int i=0; i<getIndividual(0).chromosomeColumnCount(); i++){
             columns.add(RosterManager.getDay(i));
        }

        Vector data = new Vector();
        Vector row;

        for(int row1=0; row1<getIndividual(0).ChromosomeRowSize(); row1++){

            row = new Vector(getIndividual(0).chromosomeColumnCount());
            row.add(RosterManager.getNurse(row1).getEmpName());
            for(int col=0; col<getIndividual(0).chromosomeColumnCount(); col++){
                row.add(getIndividual(0).getShift(row1, col).getShiftName());
            }    
            data.add(row);
        }
        DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(data, columns);

        table.setModel(tableModel);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

setPreferredWidth(27) can be used. Inside the method you have to add a dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
//table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    TableColumn column = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
        column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
        if(i == 0 ) column.setPreferredWidth(10);
    }
```

Comment: how to embed this code to my method. please help from where?

Comment: add it at the end of your method just change cols.length to columns.size() :)

Comment: what is cols? how you got this .length() method

Comment: in my case cols refers to column array, in your case i assume that you store columns in vector "columns" with have method size() or just simply use "getIndividual(0).chromosomeColumnCount()"  to get the column count for our for loop :D

Comment: table.setModel(tableModel);
            TableColumn column = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < columns.size(); i++) {
            column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
            if(i == 0 ) column.setPreferredWidth(200);
            else column.setPreferredWidth(150);
            }     is that correct? but i haven't seen any change

Answer (score 0):

Im using this method to change the width of columns of JTables. Just add this to your displayTable() method.

```
your_table_name.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(50);
your_table_name.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(100);
```

Comment: for(int col=0; col<columns.size(); col++){
                    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(col).setPreferredWidth(150);
 } i have used for loop but it is not working for me

Comment: for(int col=0; col<table.getColumnCount(); col++){ table.getColumnModel().getColumn(col).setPreferredWidth(150); } Use this method.

Comment: table.setModel(tableModel);
            TableColumn column = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < columns.size(); i++) {
            column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
            if(i == 0 ) column.setPreferredWidth(200);
            else column.setPreferredWidth(150);
            }     is that correct? but i haven't seen any change

Comment: Instead of  columns.size(); I have used table.getColumnCount(); so this will return the number of columns in your table.

Answer (score 0):

JTableName.getColumn(Object identifier).setWidth(WIDTH);

JTableName.getColumn(Object identifier) will return the column and set Width will change its width.